# Different listview columns copy error

Tags: c#, listview

I have 2 listviews:

- listview1 has 5 columns (0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
- listview2 has 20 columns (0, 1, 2,.., 18, 19)

I want to copy items from listview1 to listview2.

Then I have to write something

```
listview2.items[0].subitems[5]
```

but I cannot write. There is no columns here. But listview1 has 20 columns.

Anybody knows this problem's solution?

(I have to use copy function. I cannot move items one by one.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because the listview has 20 columns, doesn't mean that every item has 19 subitems.  You still have to use the .Add or .AddRange method to give value to all the possible subitems.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy the items from listview1 to listview2:

```
private static void CopySelectedItems(ListView listview1 , ListView listview2)
{
    foreach (ListViewItem item in listview1 .SelectedItems)
    {
        listview2.Items.Add((ListViewItem)item.Clone());
    }
}
```

This method can copy from list1 to list2.